# Table export jquery - display issue

Tags: jquery, html-table, export-to-excel

I have a table with a Header Row and a Sub-header row. The Header row has colspan of 3 for most cells.

When exporting to Excel, I cannot get this Header Row to:

1. Show as merged cell.
2. Leave blank spaces if it cannot merge.

As a result the Header row is shorter than the sub-header row.

I have tried the following, but it doesn't export the hidden cells.

```
<th colspan=3>Contacted</th>
<th style="display:none;" data-tableexport-display="always">Number</th>
<th style="display:none;" data-tableexport-display="always">Number</th>
```

Is anything extra needed to make `data-tableexport-display="always"` work?

TL;DR, How to deal with colspan not displaying as merged cell?

Comment: share your entire HTML and jQuery required to solve this problem. Or create a jsfiddle replication the issue. This information doesn't help at all as it is working in normal case

Comment: The data is being pulled from MySql, with 2 JS filters, so I'm not sure how to replicate it.